# integer float string differentiation programmatically

Tags: java, string, types, floating-point, integer

I want to differentiate between int/float/string input, I am trying to read the input for

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
```

this provides input in string format, if i want to check if the input is integer/float or string, how do i do? 
i did something like this

```
try{
 float i = Float.parseFloat(scan.nextLine());
 if(i%1==0){
  then it is integer
 }else{
  it is float
 }
}catch (NumberFormatException e)
 something else, may be string
}
```

But is there any method or way java provides to identify programmatically whether the input is string/int/float.

Comment: You have to define what you mean by "is the input string, int, or float".  First of all, every input is a string.  So I assume that by "string" you're looking only at strings that you don't want to count as integer or float.  So what strings count as integers?  Is "20.0" an integer?  How about "22222222222", which is too large for an `int` but fits in a `long`?  How about "2222222222222222222222", which is too large for a `long` but could be put in a `float` (with a loss of precision)?  How about "0x1234"?  "1.25e2" (which equals 125)?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of reading **String** and then parsing it to **Float** and then checking it for integer.

You can simply use **hasNext** functions of Scanner class, as shown below for integer.

```
if(sc.hasNextInt()){
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("n... "+n);
}
```

As you want exact match you can try below :

```
    String str = sc.nextLine();
    try{
        int a = Integer.parseInt(str.trim());
        System.out.println("It's Integer");
    }catch(Exception ex)
    {
        try{
            Float f = Float.parseFloat(str.trim());
            System.out.println("It's Float");
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(str);
        }           
    }
```

Comment: I forgot to add that i used hasNextInt and hasNextFloat methods and ended up seeing the both the methods returning true for integer and only if the value is float then it enters hasNextFloat. this is still not convincing

Comment: @sunil.kms123 what do you mean by "still not convincing"?

Comment: i mean, not precise to ensure the given value is integer or float

Comment: @sunil.kms123 So is there an "integer" value that the user can type in that `hasNextInt` won't think is an integer?  I still haven't seen a precise definition of what you're looking for.

Comment: @ajb.. context is I want to differentiate the input programmatically, i will have to differentiate the input as integer which can b float as well. if u can let me know which can do the differentiation i will be glad

Comment: @sunil.kms123 I'm asking you to give me a more precise definition of what you're asking for, and you're just repeating what you've said before.  You really need to think hard about your definitions.  _What inputs do you want to be treated as an integer_?  Keep in mind, whatever the user inputs is just a sequence of characters (not a numeric value), until you tell the program what to do with that sequence of characters.  What sequences of characters do you want to be considered integers, and what sequences do you want to be floats?

Comment: @sunil.kms123 And if you're still confused, please see my comment on your original question, which gives you some examples that you have to make decisions about.

Comment: @ajb, thanks since your comment includes examples, can you provide code logic which differentiates them as int, float or double. I am very clear on my question on how to differentiate integer float and other datatype. if 234 is the input it is integer as well as float, how do you differentiate? hope i am clear to you by now

Comment: @sunil.kms123 No, this is still not clear.  You still haven't told me what you want to do with 2222222222222222222222.  And I think you're still confused on one key point: when the user types in input, _it is not data of some type, where you need to figure out what type it is._  **It is always a string, and you need to DECIDE how to interpret it.**  You have still not gotten that this is your _decision_.  You can decide to let `hasNextInt()` and `hasNextFloat()` make that choice.  Is that your decision?  Yes?  No?

Comment: @ajb.. discussion is going round again to same point. i hope am clear in what am asking for differentiating the string user input to integer , float or any other type. if you can tel me how to find the range of input to categorize into int or float, please understand what am asking for before writing down your answer. thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is nothing that provides direct checking.

You can use Integer.parseInt and catch the NumberFormatException. The exception tells you it is not an integer.
Similarly, usr Float.parseFloat. If both throw exceptions, your input is a string.

Comment: yeah as i have done in my question but was interested to know if something else available or provided by java that am missing

Answer (score 0):

You could use `hasNextFoo` methods in `Scanner`. For example,

```
if(scan.hasNextInt()){
    System.out.println(scan.nextInt() + " is int");
}else if(scan.hasNextFloat()){
    System.out.println(scan.nextFloat() + " is float");
}else{
    System.out.println(scan.next() + " is String");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`java.util.Scanner` class has methods that verify if user input is of some type

```
Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
            boolean hasNextInt = userInput.hasNextInt();
```

This returns true if user entered integer.

```
boolean hasNextDouble = userInput.hasNextDouble();
        System.out.println(hasNextDouble);
```

This returns true if user entered double. Or false otherwise

Answer (score 0):

Scanner class have [couple of methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) that you can use to figure out the type of next element.

```
hasNextBigDecimal()
hasNextBigInteger()
hasNextBoolean()
hasNextByte()
hasNextDouble()
hasNextFloat()
hasNextInt()
hasNextLine()
hasNextLong()
hasNextShort()
```

and you can simply use them like

```
if(sc.hasNextInt()) {
    System.out.println(sc.nextInt() + " is an Integer.");
}
else if(sc.hasNextBoolean()) {
    System.out.println(sc.nextBoolean() + " is a Boolean.");
}
```